# Explicit Euler stability for the Heat Equation (FDM)

Tags: finite-difference-method

Why the Explicit Euler scheme for the Heat Equation is stable only if $k \leq h^2/2$ ?

Here is the difference equation:
\begin{equation}
\frac{U_j^{n+1}-U_{j}^n}{k} = \frac{1}{h^2}(U_{j+1}^n-2U_j^n+U_{j-1}^n)
\end{equation}
with $k$ the mesh size in time and $h$ the mesh size in space

Comment: please have a look at the links in my answer. If you are satisfied, please mark the answer as the solution.

Comment: To get some insight, rewrite your equation as $U^{n+1}_j = \frac{k}{h^2}U^n_{j+1}+ (1-2\frac{k}{h^2})U^n_{j}  + \frac{k}{h^2}U^n_{j-1}$. The weights $(\frac{k}{h^2}, 1-2\frac{k}{h^2}, \frac{k}{h^2})$ can only be interpreted as a Markov chain transition probabilities iff $k \leq h^2/2$.

Answer (score 3):

You can consult [Seydel](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Computational-Finance-Universitext-R%C3%BCdiger-Seydel/dp/144712992X) pages 99-106 for explicit FD or for a short summary this [link](http://www.mi.uni-koeln.de/~seydel/cfcoursenotes2015.pdf). The idea is that you cannot choose $k$ and $\frac{h^2}{2}$ independently for stability.